# Unable to move to second function after the result of the first

Tags: python

**Program Goal:** Search a defined yamlfile (`scan_dcn.yaml`) and return all lines matching the search criteria as defined in the  `function_search_search_key()` and `function_search_event_type()` functions.

**Input File - scan_dcn.yaml:**

```
search_dict:
    [
        {search_key: ["Failed to Process the file"],
        event_type: "evttyp_repl_dcn_error",
        event_description: "Failure to process DCN file",
        priority: 50,
        scan_interval: 1,
        remove_dups: True,
        category: "dcn",
        context_begin: 0,
        context_end: 1,
        reportable: False,
        offset: 0
        },
```

**Problem:**
My program will return `function_search_search_key()` but will not proceed to `function_search_event_type()`.

I would think that my problem is that I have no logic to proceed to the second function after the completion of the first.

Do I need to return a value in each function to proceed?

**Python Source Code**

```
yamlfile = open('scan_dcn.yaml', 'r')


def function_search_search_key():
    search_search_key = ['{search_key:']
    for line in yamlfile.readlines():
        for word in search_search_key:
            if word in line:
                print(line)


def function_search_event_type():
    search_event_type = ['event_type:']
    for line in yamlfile.readlines():
        for word in search_event_type:
            if word in line:
                print(line)


def main():
    function_search_search_key()
    function_search_event_type()


main()
```

Comment: You can read only once a file descriptor

Comment: `yamlfile.readlines()` reads all lines of the file in your first loop. When called again, it has no lines left to read. Try adding `lines = yamlfile.readlines()` at the top and replace `yamlfile.readlines()` with `lines`

Comment: It's not directly related to your issue, but why not use a library for the YAML parsing? You really should use a context manager to handle that file object. You don't need to use `.readlines()` here, by the way, you can simply iterate over the file object directly.

Comment: You make a completely valid point AMC. I'm new to programming and would rather build this properly from the ground up. I'm going to research a YAML parsing library and iterate over the file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first function you read the whole file with `readlines`. When you use `readlines` again in your second function you're already at the end of the file and there is no more data to read, so the `for` loop is not even entered.

But there's no need to read the file again for every function. Read the file outside of the functions and put it in a list. Then add a parameter to each of those functions that takes this list. In the function you can loop over the list.

```
def function_search_search_key(lines):
    search_search_key = ['{search_key:']
    for line in lines:
        for word in search_search_key:
            if word in line:
                print(line)


def function_search_event_type(lines):
    search_event_type = ['event_type:']
    for line in lines:
        for word in search_event_type:
            if word in line:
                print(line)


def main():
    with open('scan_dcn.yaml', 'r') as yamlfile:
        lines = yamlfile.readlines()
    function_search_search_key(lines)
    function_search_event_type(lines)

if __name__ = '__main__':
    main()
```

If you ever need to change the name of the file you can do it in one place. If you open and read the file in every single function you would have to change all occurrances of the file name.

Comment: You presented a well-formatted and good explained question. Something like this has become rare. So I'm more than glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your second function is being entered. It must if the call above it has finished.

You aren't seeing anything printed because you're attempting to loop though the same file more than once. Once you've read the file, it's exhausted. You can just re-read the file as a simple fix:

```
def function_search_search_key():
    with open('scan_dcn.yaml', 'r') as yamlfile:
        search_search_key = ['{search_key:']
        for line in yamlfile.readlines():
            for word in search_search_key:
                if word in line:
                    print(line)


def function_search_event_type():
    with open('scan_dcn.yaml', 'r') as yamlfile:  # Read the file again
        search_event_type = ['event_type:']
        for line in yamlfile.readlines():
            for word in search_event_type:
                if word in line:
                    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file descriptor only once (if you don't seek to start), so you may open your file in each function

```
def function_search_search_key():
    search_search_key = ['{search_key:']
    with open('scan_dcn.yaml') as fic:
        for line in fic:
            for word in search_search_key:
                if word in line:
                    print(line)

def function_search_event_type():
    search_event_type = ['event_type:']
    with open('scan_dcn.yaml') as fic:
        for line in fic:
            for word in search_event_type:
                if word in line:
                    print(line)
```